# How to cycle through each li or div front and backwards using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul` with around five `<li>` items. E.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>Step 1 : Take food</li>
  <li>Step 2 : Go Around</li>
  <li>Step 3 : Deliver</li>
</ul>
```

Also I have links like

```
<a href="# id="prev"> Previous</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" id="next"> Next</a>
```

I have to show the first `li` at first. Then when the `next` link is clicked, it should now show 2nd `<li>` and so on. Same for previous link.

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at the aptly named jQuery Cycle plugin.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/scrollhv.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!. But still im looking for a hand code

Answer (score 4):

following is the complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ul = $('ul');

    // hide all li
    ul.find('li').hide();

    // make first li as current
    ul.find('li').first().addClass('current').show();

    // setup previous click handler
    $('a#prev').click(function()
    {
        var prev = ul.find('li.current').prev();

        if( prev.length )
        {
            ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current').hide();
            prev.addClass('current').show();
        }
    });

    // setup next click handler
    $('a#next').click(function()
    {
        var next = ul.find('li.current').next();

        if( next.length )
        {
            ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current').hide();
            next.addClass('current').show();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only showing one element, all you need to do is use the DOM tree as a search. If you want the next element, find the element that is currently being shown, hide it, and show its next sibling. If you are doing previous, then hide the current item and select the previous sibling.

If you are unsure of how to do this, just Google around for DOM navigation. It isn't too bad.

If at all possible, I would simply use some naming convention for your LI (in the id attribute) that you could very quickly select using jQuery. For instance, if your shown element is going to have a class that the rest won't have, you can select that element quickly using jQuery, grab its id, and modify it in some way to select the previous or next element.

Answer (score 0):

as boerema said something along these lines (its untested!)
put a class "selected" on a li that starts as being shown

```
<ul>
<li>Step 1 : Take food</li>
<li class="selected">Step 2 : Go Around</li>
<li>Step 3 : Deliver</li>
</ul>


$("#prev").click(function(){
   $(".selected").hide().removeClass("selected").prev().show().addClass("Selected");
});

$("#next").click(function(){
   $(".selected").hide().removeClass("selected").next().show().addClass("Selected");
});
```

Comment: Aww, I like having people try to program themselves. Haha

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick demo : **[`http://jsbin.com/oduli4`](http://jsbin.com/oduli4)**

```
  var width = 500;
  var height = 250;
  var slide = 0;
  var speed = 500;
  var size = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  size = $('#slider').find('li').length;

  $('#slider').find('ul').width(width * size).height(height);
  $('#slider li, #slider img').width(width).height(height);

  $('#next').bind('click',function() {
    if(slide > img_width * (size - 1) *(-1)) {
          slide -= width;
         slider(slide);
    }
  });
  $('#prev').bind('click',function() {
     if(slide < 0) {
      slide += width;
        slider(slide);
    }
  });
});


function slider(slideMargin) {
  $('#slider ul').stop().animate({'left':slideMargin}, speed );
}
```

Comment: I just feel like that plugin is a lot of overhead for what he wants to do. But maybe I just don't know what his application is.